# Proxy to optimize images that are downloaded by mobiles

Tags: android, image, mobile, proxy, image-scaling

time ago I was told that there are website which you are able to request your image and it optimizes the image with the proper size depends on the mobile you have. 
It works such a proxy between your server and the mobile, so if you have a mobile or a tablet when you request your image through this proxy it will send you with the smallest size.

The problem is that I´ve been impossible to remember which websites do this kind of task.

does someone of you this sort of websites?

Thanks

Comment: an example of this kind of websites is: https://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/smushit/ but it doesn´t have this functionality that I´m looking for.

Comment: Did you mean [CloudFlare Mirage 2.0](http://blog.cloudflare.com/mirage2-solving-mobile-speed)?

Comment: Yes, that´s a good example. Thanks.